# Convert C program to C#

Tags: c#

I am writing Horspool algorithm in c#. I have a c program of the same. I have converted most part of the code but am having some difficulty converting few lines of the code.

The lines of code I am not able to figure out how to convert is

```
#define MAX 500
int t[MAX]
```

and

```
char src[100],p[100];
int pos;
clrscr();
printf("Enter the text in which pattern is to be searched:\n");
gets(src);
```

Can anyone please tell me how do I convert these lines into c#?

The source for my C program code is - http://www.c-program-example.com/2011/10/c-program-to-search-perticulur-pattern.html

Comment: All you need is `string s = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: Thank You, can you please tell me how do I convert `#define MAX 500
int t[MAX]` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#define MAX 500` would be `const int MAX = 500;`.

To use `MAX` inside an array definition, you could use something like this:

```
int[] t = new int[MAX];
```

The lines you want to convert to C# would look like this:

```
string src;
string p;
int pos;
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Enter the text in which pattern is to be searched:\n");
src = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you, I added the `const int MAX = 500;` but I want to use `MAX` inside an array, How do I write `int t[MAX]`?

Comment: @Dazzler `int[] t = new int[MAX]`

Comment: Thank you @diiN_ for the answer :)

Comment: Thank you @Psioniax for the answer :)